# Doesn't show layout from layout-xlarge folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

I am trying to run my app on my tablet which is 8" device and on my phone which is 5.2" device,
I want the layout to be displayed properly on both devices, so I read that I should create 
2 different folders: layout-large and layout-xlarge.
The 8" device should take the layout from layout-xlarge folder and the 5.2" device should take the layout from layout-large folder.
So I put the activity_main.xml on both folders and run it on the 8" device,
I don't know why but it doesn't show take the layout from the layout-xlarge folder as it should, instead I see the layout from the layout-large folder.

Tried to figure it out but I don't find much info about that problem.

any help would be appreciated,
thank you.

Comment: 5.2" is still `layout-normal` and 8" is `layout-large` - what makes you think they are `large` and `xlarge`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using size quantifiers for tablets instead of the old "small", "normal", "large" property names. They give you more control over which layouts get shown to which device.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I understand in that article that handsets doesn't use layout-sw720dp or layout-sw600dp, thses folders belong to tablets and handsets belong to the default layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layout layout-sw720dp and copy layout from layout-large to it - then the 8" device should call the layout - for Android 3.2+